# Check if a website can be embedded in an iframe via HTTP

Tags: http, iframe

Is there a way to check via headers/HTTP if a certain URL can be embedded in an iframe?

Comment: i guess you could simply check the reply mime type, and use that to determine whether or not you would want to open the reply in an iframe.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this [node.js project](http://schier.co/blog/2013/10/08/check-if-a-website-can-be-embedded-in-an-iframe-with-nodejs.html) which answers exactly your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using http://schier.co/blog/2013/10/08/check-if-a-website-can-be-embedded-in-an-iframe-with-nodejs.html the answer is to check for `x-frame-options` header and make sure it is not sameorigin or deny.